# Black screen after USB installation of Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, installation, windows-7, toshiba-satellite

I just installed 12.04 LTS on my Toshiba Satellite A135-S7403 laptop using a flash drive. The installation went perfectly, I replaced Windows 7 with the Ubuntu version and deleted all the old partitions on the hard drive.

However, after being prompted to restart, all I get is a black screen with the flashing underscore after BIOS. I have an Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 950 for my graphics card. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be caused by the GRUB boot loader installed somewhere it cant' be found. Just yesterday I was installing Ubuntu on a laptop and it wouldn't boot - I found that installer mistakingly installed the bootloader on the flash drive which I unplugged before rebooting.

See this article for instructions on [how to re-install the bootloader](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).